# Using lambda comparator with long return type

Tags: java, lambda, comparator

Something like

`arrayList.sort((long a, long b)->a - b);`

returns

> possible lossy conversion from long to int

Is there a workaround for this to avoid the long to int conversion

Comment: What type of numbers is in your ArrayList?

Comment: Don't get in the habit of writing comparator results using `a - b` to comply with the return value for a comparator.  It will eventually get you into trouble.  Just take the time to write `a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0`.  Or, when possible, use either `Long.compare` or `Integer.compare`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your comparator is invalid as it returns a *long* whereas the expected return type is *int* (the expected type for sorting function is int).

A solution will be to give a sorting condition which returns an integer (here you can control the ordering, ascending or descending):

```
arrayList.sort((x, y) -> (x < y) ? -1 : ((x == y) ? 0 : 1));
```

Another solution (which uses same logic like the previous solution):

```
arrayList.sort(Long::compareTo)
```

You can also use Comparator from java.utils

For ascending order:

```
 arrayList.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder())
```

For descending sorting:

```
arrayList.sort(Comparator.reverseOrder())
```

Answer (score 4):

Sure.  Use `Long.compare(a, b)` instead, or use the natural order (`sort(Comparator.naturalOrder())`), or `sort(Long::compare)`.